ActivityResultLauncher provides Result Cancelled as ActivityResult even when user turn on the location
I am redirecting user to the location service setting when the location is turned off of the device using below code,
private void turnOnLocation() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enable the location to perform app functionality!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent enableLocationIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        enabaleLocationLauncher.launch(enableLocationIntent);
    }

and then handling the launcher as below code,
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> enabaleLocationLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    // Here it returns RESULT_CANCELED every time even when the user turn on the location
                }
            }
    );

When user turn on the location it triggers the onActivityResult method but the ActivityResult returns as RESULT_CANCELED.
Any thought on this..
I tried debugging the code. I think code is fine there might be any other issue. I want some thought on this..

redirecting user to the location service setting when the location is turned off How do you determine that it is on or off?

@blackapps using below code we can check that the location is turned on or off :- LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Wel then use that code too in onActivityResult. Neglect the result cancel value.

@blackapps I done that already to make the functionality work, but my question is regarding why onActivityResult provides wrong output.
